# Binding Buttons to several text boxes actived based on size of values in text box

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, button, textbox

I am building a site where people can customize the shape of their product before they order it.

Ultimately there will be several buttons bound to four text boxes. As the user inputs higher values in the text box, the button that is activated changes so we know what size sheet of material will need to be ordered for this customer's design.

How can I create a button that is enabled/disabled based on the value placed in a text box?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and try something like this:

First, give your buttons an attribute `disabled="disabled"`, and then:

```
//Assuming they are typing, if it's a dropdown/select, see below

$('#input-id').on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val() >= 10 && $(this).val() <= 20) { // If the value is between 10 and 20...
      $('#button-id').removeAttr('disabled'); // Remove disabled attribute
    } else { // If the value is not our keyword...
      if(!$('#button-id').attr('disabled')) { // And the button is not disabled...
        $('#button-id').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Readd disabled attribute
      }
    }
});
```

If you are using a dropdown or select box, use `$("select option:selected")`.

Comment: Thank you for the help this is awesome, but if you don't mind just two more questions.

1) Can this code be modified so that the 'somevalue' will activate the button if it falls in a range of say between 10 and 20

2)how can I make the button dependent on values being entered into more than one text box?

Comment: @MattStephens I edited my answer to check for a number range. Simply check if the value is greater than or equal to 10 using `$(this).val() >= 10` and and less than or equal to 20 using `&& $(this).val() <= 20`. To add more ranges, simply add `else if(...)`.